# How to recreate Snapchat's sepia filter?

Tags: xcode, filter, core-image, cifilter

I am looking to make a custom filter using CIFilter modeled after Snapchat's filters, but I can't seem to get anywhere close.

This is what I'm trying to do by changing the brightness, saturation, and exposure levels. Any advice?

```
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:myImageView.image.CGImage];
    CIImage *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputBrightness", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-0.05], @"inputContrast", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], @"inputSaturation", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.05], nil].outputImage;
    CIImage *output = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, filter, @"inputEV", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil].outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    myImageView.image = newImage;
    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);
```